# Asynchronous operations with Promise.all - but operate those immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a file, which I read line by line by `line-by-line` npm package.
I want to store in my database each line (if the line matches my conditions..).
I want to store it asynchronously, but also, to wait for all saving operations to the database to finish, before I continue on to next operations.

This is my code currently:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line');
const moment = require('moment');

const saveFunc = async (filePath) => {
    const savePromises = [];

    const LBLR = new LineByLineReader(filePath);

    LBLR.on('error', (error) => {
        throw (error);
    });

    LBLR.on('line', async (line) => {
        let lineJSON;
        try {
            lineJSON = JSON.parse(line);
        } catch (e) { } // Just skip the line if cannot be parsed

        if (!!lineJSON && 'caseId' in lineJSON && 'timestamp' in lineJSON && 'message' in lineJSON) {
            if (lineJSON['message'] === "Socket.io 'connection' event") {
                const logDateString = (lineJSON['timestamp'].split(' '))[0];
                const logTimestamp = moment(logDateString, 'DD-MM-YYYY').toDate();

                savePromises.push(new LivenessLog({
                    caseId: lineJSON['caseId'],
                    eventName: 'connect',
                    timestamp: logTimestamp,
                }).save());
            }
        }
    });

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        LBLR.on('end', resolve);
    });

    await Promise.all(savePromises);
}

await saveLivenessLogs('..'); // X OPERATION -- !! --
```

So basically, I want the `.save()` operation to execute immediately (**currently it won't because I push its promise to the array, so it'll be executed only on executing `Promise.all([...])`**). But I also want to return back to `X OPERATION` only when all the `.save()` operations have been executed successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.then` after `.save()` so that it will be executed immediately (the asynchronous behavior you want)

but at the same time we need to push the resultant promise to `savePromises` array so that you can use it at the end in `Promise.all` to be confirmed that all the queries ran.

Please try something like this.

```js
savePromises.push(new LivenessLog({
    caseId: lineJSON['caseId'],
    eventName: 'connect',
    timestamp: logTimestamp,
}).save().then(data => { return data; }));
```

Comment: @shalvimuqta I am partially confident that this approach should work. Can you please try and share the results?